# How to merge data to apply to all unique conditions of a column in second data set, even when not occuring

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-manipulation

I am trying to insert new rows of data based on unique values of a column in my original data set. I have the following dummy data set:

```
sites<-c("10","10","11","11","12","12")
ID<-c("A","A","B","B","C","D")
value<-c("4","6","5","2","7","8")
dataframe<-data.frame(sites, ID, value)

sites<-c("10","10","11","11","12","12","13","14","15")
dataframe2<-data.frame(sites)
```

Producing:

```
  sites ID value
    10  A     4
    10  A     6
    11  B     5
    11  B     2
    12  C     7
    12  D     8

  sites
     10
     10
     11
     11
     12
     12
     13
     14
     15
```

For each unique value in column ID, I would like each site number from the second data frame applied, and when there is no value I would like it to print 0.

So for example, ID A would have all sites from site2 listed and when there is no value (ie for site 11, 12, 13,14) I would like it to list 0 for value.

I have tried the following:

```
mergeddata<-merge(dataframe, dataframe2, by="sites", all.y=TRUE)
```

But that only adds the new sites at the bottom with NA's for each value other than site. I want dataframe2 to be applied for each unique value under column ID, so that each ID has an occurrence of all sites. I'm not sure what the best way to go about this would be, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: can you change `all.y` to `all` and see what happens ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a job for `complete()` from package **tidyr**.  You can group your first dataset by `ID` and then use `complete()` to add rows for the `site` values from `dataframe2` within each group.

This results in having at least one row for each `site` in each `ID`.  I use the `fill` argument to add the 0 to `value` for the new rows (after converting `value` to numeric).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dataframe$value = as.numeric( as.character(dataframe$value) )

dataframe %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    complete(sites = dataframe2$sites, fill = list(value = 0) )

# A tibble: 26 x 3
# Groups:   ID [4]
   ID    sites value
   <fct> <chr> <dbl>
 1 A     10        4
 2 A     10        6
 3 A     11        0
 4 A     12        0
 5 A     13        0
 6 A     14        0
 7 A     15        0
 8 B     10        0
 9 B     11        5
10 B     11        2
# ... with 16 more rows
Warning message:
Column `sites` joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector
```

The warning message has to do with `site` being a factor in the two datasets, which `complete()` deals with by converting the two columns to characters instead.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for! Many thanks. I've run your code, but instead of zeros receive NA's. I fixed this by using dataframe[is.na(dataframe)] <- 0